# Purpose of JPA native named queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering what is the purpose of native named queries in JPA. Let's have and example:

Utility class holding native queries:

```java
class ExampleNativeQueries {
    
    static final String NATIVE_QUERY = "select * from EXAMPLE_TABLE where EXAMPLE_VALUE = :value";
}
```

and Entity class + Repository:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_TABLE")
public class Example {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "EXAMPLE_VALUE")
    private String value;
}

interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = ExampleNativeQueries.NATIVE_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Example> findByExampleValue(@Param("value") String value);
}
```

vs

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_TABLE")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Example.findByExampleValue", query = ExampleNativeQueries.NATIVE_QUERY, resultClass = Example.class)
public class Example {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "EXAMPLE_VALUE")
    private String value;
}

interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long> {
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<Example> findByExampleValue(@Param("value") String value);
}
```

Is there any difference with that 2 approaches?

Comment: My question is about somemthing else. I'm wondering what's the point of using named queries, not what they actually are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609511/what-is-the-benefit-of-the-namedquery-annotation-in-jpa#:~:text=The%20main%20benefit%20is%20that,usage%20anywhere%20in%20the%20app.

Comment: @AlanHay according to the post you linked: "The main benefit is that named queries are validated and parsed typically on application startup." - does it also concern named native queries? That example is about named JPQL query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your case.

But `@NamedNativeQuery` can provide much more flexibility for mapping result set of native query. Look at the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-named-queries). You can use `NamedNativeQuery` with `ConstructorResult` or for mapping joined-entities result set.

As an additional example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762080/how-to-map-sql-native-query-result-into-dto-in-spring-jpa-repository/).